# How to install PHPUnit in a container using a Dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, phpunit

I'm trying to install PHPUnit using a dockerfile based on the image php:7.4-fpm-alpine. My dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN touch /var/log/error_log

ADD ./php/www.conf /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

RUN addgroup -g 1000 wp && adduser -G wp -g wp -s /bin/sh -D wp

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html

RUN chown wp:wp /var/www/html

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql

RUN curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar

RUN chmod +x wp-cli.phar && mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

#install PHPunit
RUN curl -O https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-6.5.phar

RUN chmod +x phpunit-6.5.phar && mv phpunit-6.5.phar /usr/local/bin/phpunit

RUN phpunit --version
```

But I keep getting the error:

### => ERROR [7/7] RUN phpunit --version
0.4s

> [7/7] RUN phpunit --version:
> #11 0.348 /usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 1: can't open html: no such file
> #11 0.348 /usr/local/bin/phpunit: line 2: syntax error: unexpected redirection

I don't know why the phpunit command is not available. Can anyone give me a little help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
maik@LA-027:~/docker$ php phpunit-6.5.phar --version
<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

your source gives back the 302.

the phpunit-6.5.phar does not exist on the site. has to be phpunit-6.5.0.phar

simply have a look on the phar list

[phar list](https://phar.phpunit.de/)

you have installed composer, why don't you use compose to intall phpunit?

```
composer require phpunit/phpunit ^6.5
```

Comment: Hi, if I'm not mistaken, composer will install the dependecies only in a given directory. I want phpunit to be installed on the container because I will have different wordpress plugins, each one of them will use phpunit.

Comment: @churros If you're running somebody else's tests, then a separate install in each subdir is the desired behavior, as each will likely have a different requirement regarding which PHPUnit version to use. If you're going to be writing your own new tests, then you probably want to use PHPUnit v9.5 and not v6.5. Also note that PHP 7.4 is approaching end-of-life, and if you're starting a new project, you should probably target PHP 8.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Right now I'm working on a legacy application, that's why I'm targeting an old PHP version. I will try to use newer and isolated phpunit version when it's possible.

Comment: The problem was indeed 302 ElTi-42, I changed the URL and now it's working! Thanks!